# Implementing Auth0 on Node js and express

Tags: node.js, express, auth0

I'm leanring about [Auth0](https://auth0.com/es) so I create a simple back, I used `passport` and `passport-auth0` so I config [Auth0](https://auth0.com/es) some like:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');

passport.use(new Auth0Strategy({
  domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/callback', 
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) => {
  return done(null, profile);
}));
```

so my doubt is possible change the login by default???, I mean, I have my custom login on my front "http://localhost:8081/login", I would like use my login form, is possible?

note: I'm only showing the config with auth0, the rest of config express is right.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use your own login forum which you've set up at `http://localhost:8081/login`.

With Auth0 it is possible to set up your own custom login portals as shown in this article from their website [here](https://auth0.com/blog/building-beautiful-login-pages-with-auth0/). However, the caveat here is that you need to have custom domains enabled, which is a paid feature. Hope this helps!